# How to write Laravel 7 nested query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables

1. users
2. products
3. ratings

And 3 Models

1. User
2. Product
3. Rating

Relationships

1. Product belongsTo User
2. User hasMany Rating

Now I want to fetch the products who's user have rating more than 2.

How to write a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method. For example

Suppose your `ratings` table has a field `rating` that stores the rating value, and that the relationships are named

1. Product belongsTo User : relation name = `users`
2. User hasMany Rating : relation name = `ratings`

Then you can attempt

```
$products = Product::whereHas('users.ratings', function($rating){
    $rating->where('rating','>',2); 
})->get();
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks you saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a relation in your user Model with an hasManyThrough(Product::class, Rating::class) and after work with that.

have a look on laravel docs about eloquent to understand better how to make queries with it:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

And Have a look in the relations section in the documentation to see how hasManyThrough works.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction

Comment: while the `hasManyThrough` is a good suggestion, your example code does not do what the OP requests for, because in your case, it only gives product of one user, while OP is requesting for a list of all products whose users have rating above 2

Comment: @ArunAS yeah I misunderstood what he was asking for, anyway I see that you already gave him the right answer and I will leave mine so people who look for this kind of problem can have a look on the hasManyThrough and eloquent docs.